# How to change file extension from csv to xls programmatically?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Suppose that I have a folder, inside it, there is a file named `test.csv`. Now I want to change its file extension from `.csv` to `.xls`.

Is there any way to do it in Java?

Comment: I don't think that's possible... You will have to parse the csv file, create an Excel workbook (I would create an **xlsx**) and write the parsed data into that workbook.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without creating any new file", because to me, creating a file with a '.xls' extension is going to be a new file. I suppose you could read the contents, rename the file, and then write out the new contents, but that seems potentially more error prone. As to the conversion, look at [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: thanx Kevin for your reply , is it possible we can change the same file format . i am able to it like create a new xls file then read the data from csv and put into new created xls file . but i want something like without creating any new xls file read csv file content store somewhere then change the format of same csv file to xls file and put stored data into that file . hope above explanation helps you for better understanding . let me know in case of more confusion.

Comment: Read the CSV file, write the XLS file, delete the CSV file. Or read the CSV, write the XLS data into the .csv file, and rename it to .xls.